# Specific title page and other slide footer in latex beamer

Tags: beamer, header-footer

I need to create  title page like this 1st image and other slides like the 2nd image. I also need to add logo as a image (to header,footer) and footer like this..(different footer in title page)I used `\usetheme{Madrid}`. How can I add these correctly

[image: 1st slide]

[image: 2nd slide]

Comment: Why do you use Madrid?

Comment: Check out [Beamer Theme Matrix](http://www.hartwork.org/beamer-theme-matrix/) and [Beamer theme gallery](http://deic.uab.es/~iblanes/beamer_gallery/) for styles that match this. The `singapore` theme maybe closer to what you're looking for. Also see the Beamer solutions for examples of how to overlay institution logos etc. [CTAN Beamer docs](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/beamer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possibility: use `\titlepagefootline` before the frame containing the title page and `\mainfootline` after this frame. New commands \supervisor, \departament and \defense were also provided to add the information about the supervisor, the Departament, and the "Defense" text, respectively.

To get your University logo in the title page and in the inner frames, replace `ctanlion` with the name of the image file that contains the logo, in both places in which my example uses `ctanlion`. Since I didn't have any specific information about the dimensions of the logo, perhaps you'll need to modify some lengths:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\def\supervisor#1{\gdef\insertsupervisor{#1}}
\def\departament#1{\gdef\insertdepartament{#1}}
\def\defensetext#1{\gdef\insertdefensetext{#1}}

\supervisor{}
\departament{}
\defensetext{}

\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{mydefault}[1][]
{
  \vbox{}
    \vspace*{-8ex}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,sep=8pt,left,#1]{institute}
     {\usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\raisebox{-.3\height}{\inserttitlegraphic}}\quad
     {\usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vfill
  \begin{centering}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,#1]{title}
      \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \vskip1em\par
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,#1]{date}
      \usebeamerfont{author}\insertsupervisor\par\medskip
      \insertauthor
    \end{beamercolorbox}
  \end{centering}
  \vfill
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,#1]{date}
      \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate
    \end{beamercolorbox}
}

\newcommand\mainfootline{%
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[height=3ex]{ctanlion}}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=4.25ex,dp=1ex,left]{author in head/foot}%
    \raisebox{.8\baselineskip}{\parbox[t][4ex][t]{.333333\paperwidth}{\raggedright\hskip1ex\usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}%
    \raisebox{-,5\height}{\inserttitlegraphic}\hskip2ex\insertshortinstitute}}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=4.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\raisebox{.8\baselineskip}{\parbox[t][4ex][t]{.333333\paperwidth}{\centering\insertdefensetext\par\insertdepartament}}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=4.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \raisebox{.8\baselineskip}{\parbox[t][4ex][t]{.333333\paperwidth}{\raggedleft\usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex}}} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}%
}

\newcommand\titlepagefootline{%
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{%
\leavevmode%
\hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=.25ex,dp=2ex,center]{institute}
    \large\insertdepartament
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  }%
}%
}

\makeatother

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
\setbeamertemplate{title page}[mydefault]

\setbeamerfont{institute}{size=\LARGE}
\setbeamerfont{title}{size=\LARGE}
\setbeamerfont{author}{size=\large}
\setbeamerfont{institute}{size=\LARGE}

\title{The Title}
\institute{The Institute}
\supervisor{The Supervisor}
\author[Author]{The Author \\ 2876547}
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{ctanlion}}
\departament{The Departament}
\defensetext{Defense}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\titlepagefootline
\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\mainfootline
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test Frame Title}
Test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]