# Setting template background with multiple .png files

Tags: beamer

I'm a neophyte to Tex and all of it's forms, though I've used LaTeX in the past.  Mostly I've find some thing that someone else created then modified to suit my needs.  I've undertaken a project at work to put together a new, custom Beamer theme for my department and, given my neophyte status, have run into a brick wall.

Ultimately, this is what I want:

[image]

but, with my `beamerinnerthemeViciCustom.sty`:

```
\mode<presentation>

%\setbeamertemplate{background}{
%   \begin{figure}[t]
%   \hspace*{-1cm}
%   \includegraphics[width = \paperwidth]{top_box}
%   \centering
%   \end{figure}
%
%   \begin{figure}[b]
%   \hspace*{-1cm}
%   \includegraphics[width = \paperwidth]{bottom_box}
%   \centering
%   \end{figure}
%
%   \begin{figure}[b]
%   \hspace*{-1.5cm}\vspace*{-1.73cm}
%   \includegraphics[width = \paperwidth]{footer_box}
%   \centering
%   \end{figure}%
%}


% Title page
\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{ViciCustom}[1][]
{

\begin{figure}[t]
\hspace*{-1cm}
\includegraphics[width = \paperwidth]{top_box}
\centering
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[b]
\hspace*{-1cm}
\includegraphics[width = \paperwidth]{bottom_box}
\centering
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[b]
\hspace*{-1.5cm}\vspace*{-1.73cm}
\includegraphics[width = \paperwidth]{footer_box}
\centering
\end{figure}%

%   \vskip2cm%
%   \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd = 12cm, leftskip= 3cm, sep = 8pt, #1]{title     page header}
%       \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par
%   \end{beamercolorbox}%
}
\mode<all>
```

I get this:

[image]

Clearly, I'm nowhere close to what I want.  I haven't even attempted to add the logo box.  I *THINK* what I want is to have the images in the `\setbeamertemplage{background}{}` (which is why I've included it here), but when I have the images there, I get

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
```

on line 15 from my `.tex` file

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\title{Here's a thing}

\usetheme{ViciCustom}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I've found [a great response here on tex.stackexchange.com about building a template from scratch](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146529/design-a-custom-beamer-theme-from-scratch) but this is drawing boxes with `tikz` rather than inserting images.  Maybe I'm too dense to know how to modify the excellent tutorial presented above?

I'd love some guidance; as a complete newbie to Tex/LaTex/MikTex, etc., I know I need to educate myself some more but I'm incredibly frustrated that I can't even make pictures go where I want them to go.

If you'd like, here's a [link to an imgur album with all of the .png files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enwYP.jpg).

Please note that the boxes are representations of what will be in the title slide.  In other words, they're not just boxes filled with color.

Comment: Welcome! Er... why did you volunteer exactly? I mean: a custom theme for departmental use is a big job. You need to do it right if people are going to use it successfully and that means you need to know Beamer pretty well so that you can suitably adapt all the different elements and not just the ones you yourself happen to use, for example.

Comment: In any case, we need a proper minimal example which can be compiled to reproduce the problem. Right now, you've provided fragments, which will make it very difficult for anybody to reproduce the issue. You can substitute standard images from the `mwe` package for your images: `example-image-a`, `example-image-b` etc.

Comment: Don't use `figure`.

Comment: I volunteered because I thought it'd be interesting to learn more about Beamer and TeX and honestly didn't think that building three slide templates was going to be all that difficult!  Perhaps I bit off more than I could chew?

I'll get to work on the minimal working example.  If the mods deem that this questions should be deleted until I can edit to include an MWE, I'd be okay with that.

Comment: Maybe have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/301957/36296. For myself, I find it quite convenient to place such elements with `\put` inside a `picture` because this allows a very flexible positioning.

Comment: Do the answers to the linked question solve your problem?

Comment: Actually, what solved my problem as the [second answer to this question.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54577/how-do-i-customize-beamer-template)  After reading this answer, I changed my approach to building the frame backgrounds from bits and pieces to simply including a completed background image.